# Dropwizard banner.txt is not used

Tags: eclipse, banner, dropwizard

Does anyone knows how to use banner.txt in Dropwizard 0.7.1 with eclipse?

From https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/core.html#banners:

> Just add a banner.txt class to src/main/resources and it’ll print it out when your application starts:

But this does not work for me. The banner.txt is there and also one in bin folder. I found no similar problem (stackoverflow,google).

Does the file need special encoding? Is it enabled (by default) to search for banner.txt in this directory? I'm using ant+ivy instead of maven!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out, that eclipse needs the resource dir as source folder on build path:

go to project properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Folder -> go to 'src/main/resources' and activate resources -> OK

Now it works.

For the ant script use this before building the jar (change ant vars if needed):

```
    <copy todir="${bin}" flatten="true">
        <fileset dir="${src}" casesensitive="yes">
          <include name="**/banner.txt"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```

'flatten' attribute:

> Ignore the directory structure of the source files, and copy all files
>   into the directory specified by the todir attribute
>   (quote:http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)